# Is this solved with Linear Regression?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

So I have this exercise and I want to see if I am understanding it correctly.
The exercise is this:

> Given the points (2,1) and (-1,3). Give the equation of the line
>   through these two points. The equation should have the form
>
> W0 + W1*X1 + W2*X2 = 0
>
> In this equation (0,1,2) are the so-called weights of the
>   line.

So, from what I am understanding, to solve this I will uses linear regression. Here we have two independent variables (X1 and X2) and one dependent variable (Y=0).

In most examples I saw on the internet, the data points where presented in a table. In this case I would get this? :

X1: 2  | -1

X2: 1  |  3

Y:  0  |  0

Question 1) Are all the above correct assumptions?

Question 2) And if yes, any tips on how to solve it? Most formulas that I found, to calculate W0, W1 and W2, involved using Y in them, which in this case made everything zero.

Comment: no. You have (only) two points and so Linear regression is not appropriate. It does not apply. Two points determine a line.

Comment: hint: instead of thinking of the two points as x-y pairs think of them as x1-x2 pairs. Use regular methods to find the line through the two points, calculate the slope and use point-slope formula. Then rearrange the result to look like the desired form...again instead of Y use X2 and instead of X use X1.

Answer (score 0):

You mioght use linear regression, but it should also be possible to calculate the parameters directly:

The normal equation of a plane is
$$
n \cdot u = d \iff \\
n_1 x_1 + n_2 x_2 = d
$$
which is of the form
$$
w_0 + w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 = 0
$$
If $n$ is a unit vector
$$
n_1^2 + n_2^2 = 1
$$ 
then $\lvert d \rvert$ is the distance of the plane to the origin.

You have two points given, which will yield three equations in three unknowns $n_1, n_2, d$.

$$
(2,1): \quad 2 n_1 + 1 n_2 = d \\
(-1, 3): \quad -n_1 + 3 n_2 = d \\
n_1^2 + n_2^2 = 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with the basic question, find the equation of the line passing through  the points, $(2,1)$ and $(-1,3)$.  First, find the slope of the line. 
$$
m = {\Delta{y} \over \Delta{x}} = {(y_1 - y_0) \over (x_1 - x_0)} = {(3-1) \over (-1 -2)} = -{2\over3}
$$

Then, use the point slope formula
$$(y-y_0) = m (x-x_0)$$
we have, $m = -{2\over3}$ and choose the first point, $(2,1)$ 
$$(y - 1) = {-2\over3}(x-2)$$
let's just multiply both sides by 3 to get rid of the fraction.
$$(3y - 3) = -2(x-2)$$
$$(3y - 3) =-2x +4$$
bring everybody over to the left side...
$$2x + 3y -3 -4 = 0$$
$$2x + 3y -7 = 0$$
now simply re-write that in the requested form. Write $x_1$ in place of $x$ and write $x_2$ in place of $y$.
$$-7 + 2x_1 + 3x_2= 0$$